# 19.1 Gnome themes no sounds

Tags: sound, 19.10

I do get sound from my system, when playing a video for example. There are also certain sounds by default, like emptying the trash. However there are no startup sounds, opening or closing windows, you know the usual system sounds.

I googled the heck out of it, installed tweak-tools, created my own sound theme and tried using that. But no luck. Here is what is in my sounds folder.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:26 alsa
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:26 freedesktop
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:27 gnome
drwxr-xr-x   4 tony tony  4096 Feb 22 15:41 Smooth
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:29 sound-icons
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:28 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 17 08:29 Yaru
```

You can see the one I created, I was wondering about the file ownership.
Interesting that when I look in Tweaks the only ones that show up are "Custom", "Default", "Yaru" and mine "Smooth".

Any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks!
-Tony

Comment: What OS/release are you running?   Ubuntu releases us a *yy.mm* format and there was no release in 2019-January.  Other OSes do have a 19.1, but not Ubuntu.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the info I get:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 19.10
Release: 19.10
Codename: eoan